# Sharpening an established inequality?

Tags: inequality

Nesbitt's inequality states that
$$\frac{x}{y+z}+\frac{y}{z+x}+\frac{z}{x+y}
\;\ge\;\frac{3}{2}\tag{Nes}$$
holds for all $\,x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}^{>0}$. Applying Cauchy-Schwarz to it yields
$$\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)
\left[\frac{1}{(x+y)^2}+\frac{1}{(y+z)^2}+\frac{1}{(z+x)^2}\right]
\;\ge\;\frac{9}{4}\tag{1}$$
and **my question:** *Does this remain true upon replacing the first factor  by* $xy+yz+zx\,$?

> Please prove or reject
>   $$(xy+yz+zx)\left[\frac{1}{(x+y)^2}+\frac{1}{(y+z)^2}+\frac{1}{(z+x)^2}\right]
> \;\ge\;\frac{9}{4}\tag{2}
> $$
>   with  $\,x,y,z>0$ as before.

- There's the estimate $\,xy+yz+zx\le\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)\,$ obtained from $\operatorname{(AM\ge GM)}$. It can get very coarse, e.g. choose $x=1$ and both $y,z$ close to zero, but it appears as if the other factor in brackets can compensate such that $(2)$ still holds true.
  This is a pro, but not a proof.
- When trying to prove $(2)$ along the same lines as above I am stuck: Applying Cauchy-Schwarz to
  $$\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{\sqrt{xy}}{x+y}$$ gives the needed LHS of $(2)$, but by $\operatorname{(AM\ge GM)}$ the cyclic sum is bounded *above* by $\frac{3}{2}$.
  So this is a con, but not a counterexample.